# What is the best way to handle inter container communication in a IBM Bluemix container group?

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I have a IBM Bluemix container group with multiple containers. 
I have several use-cases (change global app variables, distribute API load etc.) where a REST API call to to a container, needs to inform other containers in the group.

What is the best way to handle this? Does bluemix provide any container linking among containers in a group?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities for this.

Perhaps the simplest would be to write to a shared volume, which also has the advantage of persisting for new containers joining the group to see as well.

The container could also talk directly through the LB to get to the other containers ( look at the "loadbalancer_fip" environment variable inside the container in the group ), but that's not guaranteed to hit every container in the group, even with a few tries.

A third choice would be to use something like https://www.amalgam8.io/ and have each container check in on startup, then they can route to each other via their service name.  This also lets them easily get to other container groups/services in that same space.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for taking time to answer this. I will explore amalgram8, along with one other option I am currently looking at, which is having a database pub/sub and application threads listening to it. We use Mongo and Java, so theoretically it should be possible. The one problem I could see happening with micro service discovery such as amalgam8 is that, when a container crashes the application needs to remove that container from the service discovery, which is a catch 22 situation. isn't it?

Comment: For amalgam8, you'd probably configure it with the sidecar ( https://www.amalgam8.io/docs/sidecar.html ) and then have the automatic health checking enabled ( https://www.amalgam8.io/docs/sidecar-configuration.html#health-checks ) to automatically cause it to be deregistered if it goes away.  As to what watches that... not sure.  Would only really need one level of cross checking to handle it (i.e. sidecar reports to ring, ring watchdogs all sidecars as well), but I'm not clear on what that exact mechanism is for amalgam8.